# Get CRC checksum of an NSData in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, crc

How can I count CRC (32 or 64) of an NSData object in Objective-C?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028742/compute-a-checksum-on-the-iphone-from-nsdata? Not quite CRC, but will MD5 do?

Comment: No, the problem is that I need CRC :(

Answer (score 44):

Use `crc32()` function from `zlib` library:

```
#import <zlib.h>

NSData *data;

// ...

unsigned long result = crc32(0, data.bytes, data.length);
NSLog(@"CRC32: %lu", result);
```

Make sure to link `libz` library with your project:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From iOS11 use this:

```
unsigned long result = crc32_z(0, data.bytes, data.length);
```