# How to check CRC32 of NSData?

Tags: iphone, crc32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get CRC checksum of an NSData in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115059/get-crc-checksum-of-an-nsdata-in-objective-c)

I can't find any implementation of CRC32 algoryghm in xcode. Can anybody help me calculate it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115059/get-crc-checksum-of-an-nsdata-in-objective-c

Answer (score 16):

`libz` has a `crc32()` function. To use it with NSData, try this simple category:

Your header:

```
@interface NSData (CRC32)
- (uint32_t)CRC32Value;
@end
```

Your implementation:

```
#include "your header"

#include <zlib.h>

@implementation NSData (CRC32)
- (uint32_t)CRC32Value {
    uLong crc = crc32(0L, Z_NULL, 0);
    crc = crc32(crc, [self bytes], [self length]);
    return crc;
}
@end
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this for streaming data? Can I just repeatedly call crc32() when I receive data. I would like to do this for an NSURLConnectionDelegate to checksum the results of large downloads streamed directly to disk.

Comment: See the documentation for `crc32()`. Effectively, yes.