# Check is the downloaded mp4 file is proparly downloaded to play. - iphone sdk

Tags: ios, ios4, video, download, mp4

I have developed the code for downloading the mp4 video from server. It does work perfectly sometime but sometime the video which is downloaded is not proper so its not playing.
Sometime it that downloaded video is off just 2kb which is not the correct or might be not downloaded properly. 
So is there any way to check is the downloaded mp4 file is correct?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can check the md5 hash for data integrity ...

Comment: Thanks Ankit for replay.. But can you please provide some more detail about it. may be link to any blog.

Comment: Ankit, I should accept only the answer which are correct or the one which provide some correct path. what do you think?

Comment: Hello Satish, Did you find some solution? I am also facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a iPhone developer, but I would suggest computing a checksum on the file downloaded and compare that to a checksum that can be requested from where the file is downloaded.

Check for instance [Compute a checksum on the iPhone from NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028742/compute-a-checksum-on-the-iphone-from-nsdata) for a checksum example.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue when using `AVAssetExportSession` to cache a video that was being streamed from the server. I solved this by using [isPlayable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasset/1385974-isplayable) on `AVAsset`. If the property returned `false` I would remove the cached video and stream it from the server instead. Hope this solves your problem.