# Game Center GKTurnBasedMatch problems with matchData property

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, game-center, gamekit

I'm creating a Game Center game with `GKTurnBasedMatch` matches. I'm having a problem where the `readonly` `matchData` property on a `GKTurnBasedMatch` does not seem to be properly stored on Game Center servers.

I'm using [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797672/1148702) to generate an md5 checksum on the `matchData` `NSData`, both when being sent and received to and from the Game Center servers.

I note the checksum of my `NSData` game data object when I send the `matchData` using the `GKTurnBasedMatch` instance method `endTurnWithNextParticipants:turnTimeout:matchData:completionHandler:`.

The opponent then retrieves the matches using `GKTurnBasedMatch`'s class method `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:`, and when the matches arrive (no errors), I note the checksum again.

The two checksums do not match, and the resulting data are clearly not identical based on the reconstructed game. I have checked in the two accounts that the `matchID` property on my `GKTurnBasedMatch` objects are identical.

I've also performed the following test:

```
NSLog(@"matchID: %@ matchData checksum: %@",
                    match.matchID, 
                    [Utilities md5StringFromData:match.matchData]);

// match is a valid `GKTurnBasedMatch` object.
[match endTurnWithNextParticipants: @[ opponent ] // My `GKTurnBasedParticipant` opponent
                       turnTimeout:600
                         matchData:data // This is a valid NSData object
                 completionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
                      if (nil != error) {

                          NSLog(@"%@", error);

                      } else {

NSLog(@"Successfully ended turn.");

[GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error) {

    if (nil != error) {

        NSLog(@"Error getting matches: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    } else {

        for (GKTurnBasedMatch *match in matches) {

            NSLog(@"matchID: %@ matchData checksum: %@", 
                        match.matchID, 
                        [Utilities md5StringFromData:match.matchData]);

        }

    }
}];

                      }
}];
```

In this sample, where I end the turn with data and immediately retrieve the matches from Game Center, the data match. However, when I access the `matchData` from the opponent's Game Center account and device, they differ.

Anyone encountered anything like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I discovered the solution on [Apple's Dev Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/769035).

It turns out that `loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:` doesn't always grab the most up-to-date `matchData`. To make sure you have the most recent version, make sure you call the `loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler:` method on your `GKTurnBasedMatch` object.

Comment: Do you have any idea what the reasoning is behind this implementation?

Comment: I assume the rationale is that they'd like to minimize network requests and do optimal caching, but man, this was driving me insane until I found the solution.

Comment: It seems like broken caching to me. Even the documentation does not provide any notice of the fact that the game objects may not be current. I was also going nuts over this.

Comment: The docs don't explicitly mention these possible stale objects, but if you search for these methods in the Game Center Programming Guide, it seems maybe a tiny bit plausible that what they wrote corresponds to how it works. But yeah, I'm with you, should have been made more clear.

Comment: hi, When I get Take turn value. the values of previous match is over ride with the current match. how can I solve this .

Comment: Vineesh TP: I'm not sure I understand your question!